# Como abrir uma janela de seleção de arquivo em Python com GTK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk-python

Tenho uma aplicação em Python utilizando interface gráfica GTK. Esta interface é composta por uma tela com entrada de dados um botão, **o objetivo do programa é salvar dados em planilhas em um diretório específico**.

Preciso que, ao clicar no botão, seja aberto uma tela para escolher o diretório em que  este arquivo será salvo.

```
def botao_arquivos(widget):
    #comando para abrir a pasta dos arquivos    
    pass
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "abrir uma pasta"? Exibir em tela quais são os arquivos? Fazer visualização em árvore desses arquivos?

Comment: @FilipeSantos Não, não está claro. Abrir a pasta é muito vago, aliás, tecnicamente falando, não existe esse negócio de abrir pasta. Eu julgo que você queira dizer que quer mostrar o conteúdo da pasta pelo gerenciador de arquivos do sistema.

Comment: @FilipeSantos qual a interface gráfica que você está usando? Atualmente só podemos fazer um `ls`, no máximo, e retornar a lista de ficheiros dentro da pasta

Comment: Aaaah bom, você quer abrir um _dialog_ de _save_, se eu não me engano a interface gráfica (do sistema operacional) te dá alguma opção. Aliás, quando o @JeffersonQuesado perguntou qual interface gráfica você está usando ele falou a interface gráfica do sistema operacional xD

Comment: @FilipeSantos Aqui o ponto de partida para o que você quer fazer (http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dialogs.html#filechooserdialog)

Comment: Agora eu entendi a questão.

Comment: Pensei em executar um cmd no terminal pelo python tipo nautilus para abrir a pasta, ou xdg-open o que acham?

Comment: gente - não é tão dificil assim  -todos os frameworks para programas gráficos tem algo do tipo  já pronto. Eu não sei se antes da pergunta ser editada estava claro que o AP estava usando GTK - se não estivesse, isso é o que tinha que ser verificado. Mas uma vez que sabemos que usa GTK é só ver a documentação lá - seria análogo se fosse Tkinter, Qt5, win32com , etc... "abrir um programa separado usando o nautilus" seria bem bizarro.

Comment: @jsbueno isso só ficou claro na segunda revisão

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O framework GTK tem o "FileChooserDialog" que é uma janela completa para navegar no sistema de arquivos, e permite ou a escolha de um arquivo (ou diretório) já existente (ação de "open"), ou que o usuário escreva um novo nome (ação de "save").

Uma vez que sua questão, ao contrário das práticas indicadas, não tem nada do seu código, não tenho também como dar um exemplo de uso (sem escrever um programa inteiro, funcional).

A documentação do FileChooser, como usado pelo Python está aqui:
http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dialogs.html#filechooserdialog

basicamente, a chamada para criar o diálogo é:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk

...

dialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog(
    title="Please choose a file", window=sua_janela_principal_,
    action=gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
    buttons=(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.ResponseType.OK))
)
```

Depois que você construir o diálogo e configurar os parâmetros desejados, chame o método `run`: a thread corrente do seu programa pausa enquanto o diálogo é usado pelo usuário - depois que este escolher e confirmar um arquivo, verifique qual foi o nome escolhido chamando:

```
nome = dialog.get_filename()
dialog.destroy()
```

Na url acima há um programa completo usando o diálogo com mais detalhes (o que fazer no caso do usuário cancelar a ação, por exemplo)

Comment: tem como abrir de outra forma, fazendo por exemplo um comando pelo terminal de alguma forma que eu faça isso pelo sistema, para abrir um diretório definido?

Comment: consegui criar a tela e abrir a pasta com os relatórios, mas agora como faço para abrir? Tenho arquivos csv e html. Uso algum comando do sistema para abrir?

Comment: o diálogo de arquivos te devlve um nome de arquivo com o caminho completo. Daí voce usa o seu programa pra fazer o que quiser com esse nome. Em particular para renderizar arquivos HTML + CSS para o usuario, a forma mais prática é abrir um navegador externo apontando para o seu arquivo html - o Python tem o modulo "webbrowser" para fazer isso, veja a documentação dele.

Comment: á se voce precisa pegar os dados que estão nesse arquivo, você le os dados pra memoria, e programa a extração dos dados relevantes - com if/else, expressões regulares ou o uso de módulos especializados como o beautifulsoup